# HI ANOVA vs Regression

Tags: regression, anova, repeated-measures

I am conducting a repeated measures study and comparing two experimental conditions and the control to see if they still will have an effect.

I hypothesize that VR environment will impact memory recall, and I want to compare the recall ability on the VR condition, the Desktop condition, and the control condition.

I am thinking of using an ANOVA, but I have been reading the multiple regression could also work ... a little confused, so any help would be great thank you.

Comment: If you plan to adjust for some others variables, linear regression should provide a better framework. One other advantage of regression model is to compute effect measures easily interpretable. Feel free to provide reproductible example if you want a more comprehensive answer regarding the differences between both.

Comment: This isn’t the whole story, but the classical ANOVA is a special case of the general linear regression.